# What's the difference between a Holodeck and a Holosuite?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, holodeck

The Enterprise D had a holodeck for training, entertainment, and plot contrivance, but on DS9, the holo-projecting room was referred to as a 'holosuite'.

What is the technical difference between a holodeck and a holosuite?

Comment: The difference is nine letters.

Comment: I suspect (thus no answer but a comment) that the first is on a ship, hence a **deck** and the second is a room in Quark's establishment, hence a **suite**.

Comment: I think @bitmask nailed it on the head, however in nautical terms a "deck" would imply the entire level, a more correct term on a ship would be a holo *compartment*

Comment: Marketing! Call it a “holosuite” and you can charge double.

Comment: @Monty129 Or maybe "Holo Bay", like Sick Bay?

Comment: @Izkata that could also work.

Comment: Not a technical difference, but before Starfleet occupied the station Quark's holosuites were primarily a hight-tech brothel (and still used as such by some customers afterward IIRC), so the term Holosuite may have been a reference to seedy motels.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Essentially, there's no difference in terms of the technology. The implication is that a [holosuite](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holosuite) is smaller and can accomodate one or two people (in a small simulation) whereas a [holodeck](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holodeck) is a larger space that can accomodate dozens of people.

Additionally, a holodeck is a *dedicated* space with built-in equipment whereas a holosuite (at least the DS9 versions) are described as '*modular*' suggesting that almost any room can be made into a holosuite.

It also makes linguistic sense that a holo**deck** would be situated on a ship's **deck**, whereas a holo**suite** could be any room designated for the purpose. The Enterprise-D apparently contained multiple holodecks as well as various *individual* holographic environments analagous to a single-person 'suite'.

In an interview for "[The Deep Space Log Book: A Second Season Companion](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Deep_Space_Log_Book:_A_Second_Season_Companion)" Herman Zimmerman uses the terms interchangeably;

> "Holosuites are like the holodeck of Next Generation and we can
>   program pretty much any kind of experience for any kind of location we
>   want to. But what we are doing on Deep Space Nine that we weren't able
>   to do on Next Generation is we see the inside of the holodeck and we
>   see the machinery that runs it. When we did Next Generation we were in
>   a budget constraint that made us do a set that is a wireframe look;
>   it's a grid of squares when the holodeck is not activated and they
>   just see a black void with yellow grids. In the Cardassian holodeck
>   when the lights go off, so to speak, you see the machinery that
>   creates the imagery. It's a step forward for us and it's something
>   we've always wanted to do on Next Generation and we were never able to
>   achieve".

Comment: `a holosuite is smaller and can accomodate one or two people (in a small simulation)` - The one exception I can immediately think of is when Molly O'Brien has her time travel trip and Miles and Keiko take her to the holosuite and visit the wide open fields of the planet she grew up on.

Comment: And then there are the times when the entire command crew visits the holosuite, i.e. Vic's bar. Or, when Sisko challenges the Vulcans to a baseball game. Then they have two full teams in one simulation.

Comment: @Xantec - Yup. The technology is wildly inconsistent. The Memory Alpha page posits that the holosuites could somehow be networked together with smaller groups in multiple suites

Comment: The only option I can think of for a lot of it is that perhaps they used multiple holosuites running a single simulation at times. It never is said how many of them Quark had and we infrequently see the characters actually entering or exiting them.

Comment: @Xantec - Or that O'Brien has somehow jerry-rigged them together in order to create a much larger environment. There's simply no canon explanation

Comment: I think if anyone was doing rigging to Quark's holosuites it would be Rom. When Sisko et al got stuck in Bashir's simulation Eddington was astonished at how convoluted their hardware was.

Comment: Even on a TNG holodeck, I think you have to assume that when the characters move apart further than the size of the deck, then when they see each other from a distance they are each looking at a holographic image of the other person that replicates all the behavior of whatever the real person is doing. So, even if a holosuite can only accomodate a single person I don't see that there should be a problem with groups of people interacting within the same simulated world.

Comment: @Xantec It's not very satisfying, but as far as I remember the canon answer is that participants are "treadmilled" around so they're never too far apart, and the holodeck/suites will bend light so that they only _look_ far apart to each other

Comment: @Izkata that would certainly work in the majority of cases, but I could see there being some issues in more vigorous programs where people might hit each other in the close quarters, like Worf's training programs. Especially if the participants bring their own weapons.

Comment: @Xantec - why would physical contact be a problem? The holograms are combined with force fields so that fake holographic people feel just as solid as anyone else. So likewise if two real people at different locations were each interacting with a holographic projection of the other one, then each could encounter exactly the same physical resistance as if they were really in contact.

Comment: @Hypnosifl If myself and two friends were to be in a holosuite taking part in a medievil combat simulation and one of us was using a real (i.e. brought from outside the holosuite) longsword or Zweihänder, it would be entirely likely that the long blade could pose a hazard to the other real people in the room, even if in the simulation they were no where near each other.

Comment: @Xantec - since the holodeck/holosuite are using constantly shifting force fields anyway, perhaps the safety protocols would involve creating a temporary shield if someone were about to be injured by a real object moving towards them. But in a large space like the holodeck the force treadmill would probably keep people far apart in real space if they were swinging weapons around, and with smaller holosuites maybe each person taking part in the same simulation would have to use their own suite, just interacting with holographic images of the other participants.

Answer (score 3):

Holosuites are much smaller than Holodecks. But, in typical Ferengi fashion, it's all about the profit. Several smaller Holosuites can realize more profit than one large Holodeck. Think about the analogy of buying bulk items at the store. Buying one large item in x volume container is more expensive 'out of pocket' but with a lower per-unit cost than two smaller items that total the same amount of product. The smaller item is less expensive 'out of pocket' but the mark-up is higher per unit, thereby maximizing profit. Marketing 101.

Answer (score 1):

Holosuites are Ferengi and holodecks are Federation tech,  Its implied that the Federation was less advanced in holotech at the time of the first galaxy class ships and that Ferengi had been working with it longer.
(early episodes of TNG show it was new tech and was not in civilian use at large yet and Quark talks about the Holosuite King when hes selling fake pieces of him as if hes old and Ferengi live a long time so its implied they had it a lot longer)